# Fetch a line containing a word and some value in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a multiple lines in a variable in the below format.

```
edit <> user:admin time:5/22/2021 03:00:AM  point: was:3.4 
edit <> user:admin time:5/22/2021 04:00:AM  registered: was:false
```

Let us suppose the above two lines are in a variable a.

```
    set $a "edit <> user:admin time:5/22/2021 03:00:AM  point: was:3.4
edit <> user:admin time:5/22/2021 04:00:AM  registered: was:false"
```

I am trying to find the line which contains the string "edit" ,"point" and also trying to fetch its "was:".
Is there a easier way in tcl to do this match and get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl, you'd do this with the help of the `-line` option to `regexp`:

```
# I've added a few newlines for clarity only
if {[
    regexp -line {^edit\s.*\spoint: (?:was:(\S*))?} $a matchedLine was
]} then {
    puts "matched line: $matchedLine"
    puts "was: $was"
} else {
    puts "no match"
}
```